# WooCommerce - Can't attach more than 3 pdf files to email

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to attach a few pdfs to my custom welcome email. Each pdf has the exact same size of about 2Mb. The email is sent if I don't attach more than 3 pdfs.

```
 function attach_coupons_pdf_to_email($attachments, $status, $order)
{
    the_log("\n " . $status .  " \n");
    if (isset($status) && strcmp($status, "wc_welcome") == 0)
    {
        array_push($attachments, trailingslashit(ABSPATH) . "coupons/gutschein-1488685005124.pdf");
        array_push($attachments, trailingslashit(ABSPATH) . "coupons/gutschein-1488704520421.pdf");
        array_push($attachments, trailingslashit(ABSPATH) . "coupons/gutschein-1488704521893.pdf");
      //  array_push($attachments, trailingslashit(ABSPATH) . "coupons/gutschein-1488704520454.pdf"); Doesn't send anymore
    }
    return $attachments;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_coupons_pdf_to_email', 2, 3);
```

I can't believe that I can't attach more than about 6Mb to an email. The maximum upload size of my webhoster is 200Mb and the memory_limit is 256Mb.

Do you know of any other restrictions concerning file attachments?

Comment: Any errors? Have you checked your WP / Woo logs?

Comment: Just checked everything and installed Error Log Monitor Plugin, but nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

`post_max_size` the default is 8MB.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: You are right, but if I do this: var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size') );   I get 200M as output.